# ImageView won't show image when set by setImageBitmap()

Tags: android, imageview

I am having problems getting an existing image on the sdcard to display.

```
ImageView _photoView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_photo);

File photoFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Session.PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
rawFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(photoFile);
Bitmap origPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(rawFileInputStream, null, new BitmapFactory.Options());

_photoView.setImageBitmap(origPhoto);
Log.d(TAG, origPhoto.getWidth() + " - " + origPhoto.getHeight());
```

The photo does exist and the dimensions show up as displayed, but nothing appears within the ImageView tag

```
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/img_photo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I tried to set the height to a fixed size, but I still can't see the photo.

I've seen a few posts on SO regarding this issue, but none of them have yet been answered.

Any ideas?

** Update
If I load the file directly, instead of through a filestream it works

```
Bitmap origPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/" + Session.PHOTO_FILE_NAME);
double scale = MAX_WIDTH * 1.0 / origPhoto.getWidth();
int height = (int)(origPhoto.getHeight() * scale);
Bitmap scaledPhoto = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(origPhoto, MAX_WIDTH, height, true);
_photoView.setImageBitmap(origPhoto);
```

but if I then add the `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()` method call it no longer works and the image is not displayed.

Comment: Something else is wrong, `setImageBitmap(Bitmap)` definitely works.

Comment: Right you are.  I replaced the file streaming with `Bitmap scaledPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/" + Session.PHOTO_FILE_NAME);` and it now works.

Comment: Unfortunately, as soon as I add the a line of code to scale the image it no longer works.  See the update

Comment: I swapped devices and the original code then worked.  I then did a full uninstall on the other device and it now works there as well...

Comment: Ah the good ol' clean/rebuild trick. Glad to hear you got it working!

Comment: Check if the Bitmap returned by decodeStream is not null.

Comment: @chris delete post or put in answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the file streaming with Bitmap scaledPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/" + Session.PHOTO_FILE_NAME); and it now works (what was mentioned in the Update)