# Image view wont display image setImageBitmap()

Tags: android

This works on Emulator (i use genymotion) but for some reason it wont work on a real device.
image view wont display the image, i am sure that it is not empty because it shows path file. here's the code. when i start the app, all works fine except that the file (image) is not displaying on the image view. i tried looking into the logcat and there's no error regarding why the image won't display. thanks for answering

```
ImageView img_logo;
    protected static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
    protected static final int FILE_REQUEST = 2;
    private Uri imageCaptureUri;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_account, container, false);
        try{
        firstname = getArguments().getString("firstname");
        lastname = getArguments().getString("lastname");
        username = getArguments().getString("username");
        cno = getArguments().getString("cno");
        email = getArguments().getString("email");
        address = getArguments().getString("address");
        userID = getArguments().getString("userID");

        fullname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        tv_uname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        tv_cno = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_cno);
        tv_email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_email);
        tv_address = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user_address);

        //upload photo
        startDialog();

        DisplayImage();
        fullname.setText(firstname + " " + lastname);
        tv_uname.setText(username);
        tv_cno.setText(cno);
        tv_email.setText(email);
        tv_address.setText(address);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;
    }
```

method startDialog()

```
private void startDialog(){
        final String[] items = new String[] {"From Cam", "From SD Card"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Choose Action: ");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (which == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_avatar" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");
                    imageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    try {
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageCaptureUri);
                        intent.putExtra("return data", true);

                        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    dialog.cancel();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete Action using"), FILE_REQUEST);
                }
            }
        });
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        //image
        txt_image_path = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.image_path);
        img_logo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.display_image);
        img_logo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

on Activity Result()

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
            return;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        String path = "";
        if(requestCode == FILE_REQUEST){
            imageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            path = getRealPathFromURI(imageCaptureUri);
            if(path != null){
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
            }else{
                path = imageCaptureUri.getPath();
            }

        }else {
            path = imageCaptureUri.getPath();
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

        }

        img_logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        txt_image_path.setText(path);

    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImageView won't show image when set by setImageBitmap()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6538843/imageview-wont-show-image-when-set-by-setimagebitmap)

Comment: use picasso to load ur image from the url. save urself from havig to write a lot of boilerplate code. http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: i am not loading an image from url, the image is in the external storage or camera on phone.

Comment: `i am sure that it is not empty`. ??? What is not empty? The bitmap you assing to the image view will be null. Please check. For the rest: why do you post so much irrelevant code?

Comment: `path = imageCaptureUri.getPath();`. After that statement you are not trying at all to obtain a bitmap. And you do not inform the user about it.

Answer (score 0):

try this modified code to find errors in logcat

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,
    strong textIntent  data
    {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
        return;
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    String path = "";
    if(requestCode == FILE_REQUEST){
        imageCaptureUri = data.getData();
        path = getRealPathFromURI(imageCaptureUri);
        if(path != null){
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        }else{
            path = imageCaptureUri.getPath();
        }

    }else if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST &&
    resultCode ==   RESULT_OK) {

    try
    {path = imageCaptureUri.getPath();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        img_logo.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        txt_image_path.setText(path);
       }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();

    }



    }
```